# syntax error on token extends expected

Tags: java, generics

[image]I have created following classes using generics

```
public interface FacilityMasterService extends AbstractAssessmentLevelService<E extends AbstractAssessmentLevelBean> {
}

public interface AbstractAssessmentLevelService extends AbstractAssessmentService<E extends AbstractAssessmentBean> {}

public interface AbstractAssessmentService extends GenericService<E extends GenericBean> {}

public interface GenericService<E> {}

public class AbstractAssessmentLevelBean extends AbstractAssessmentBean {

}

public class AbstractAssessmentBean extends GenericBean {

}

public class GenericBean{

}
```

But in interfaces I am getting following error Syntax error on token "extends", , expected
how to resolve this.
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
... extends AbstractAssessmentLevelService<E extends AbstractAssessmentLevelBean>
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(You can't extend a class without specifying a concrete type argument.)

Perhaps you're after this:

```
public interface FacilityMasterService<E extends AbstractAssessmentLevelBean>
        extends AbstractAssessmentLevelService<E> {

}
```